# How to pass variable in bash for php command

Tags: bash, variables, escaping

On bash funcion I need pass varible por a external command (php)

```
panel=$(php -r '$ini_array = parse_ini_file("/root/.name/name.ini");echo $ini_array['panel'];')
```

Work properly.

But I need pass path on variable and key of array also.
Try several form but all fails. '', "", ...

```
php -r '$ini_array = parse_ini_file(`$sPath`);echo $ini_array["$sKey"];'
```

It's possible?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the variable through the environment, and retrieve it from the environment on the PHP side.

```
sPath=$sPath sKey=$sKey \
  php -r '$ini_array = parse_ini_file($_ENV["sPath"]);echo $ini_array[$_ENV["sKey"]];'
```

The initial `sPath=$sPath` and `sKey=$sKey` are not necessary if you have used `export` to put your shell variables in the environment already.

Comment: It dosen't work on shell and not work on bash script
sPath=/root/.tamainut/tamainut.ini
root@espejo [~/tamainut/sistemas]# sKey=panel
root@espejo [~/tamainut/sistemas]# php -r '$ini_array = parse_ini_file($_ENV["sPath"]);echo $ini_array[$_ENV["sKey"]];'
<font color=ff0000>
Warning: parse_ini_file(): Filename cannot be empty! in Command line code on line 1
On bash script also.

Comment: @AbdelKarimMateosSanchez You didn't copy my example exactly. You can't simply set the value as a shell variable; you have to export it into the environment. You do this by either putting `key=value` pairs ON THE SAME COMMAND (as I do in the example -- it's why there's a backslash on the end of the first line, making the second line a continuation), or using the `export` keyword.

Comment: @AbdelKarimMateosSanchez ...so, to be more explicit: Instead of running `sKey=panel` and `sPath=/root/.tamainut/tamainut.ini` as separate commands, you need to put `sKey=panel sPath=/root/.tamainut/tamainut.ini` immediately before the `php`, on the same line of script.